# Build query for nested structure in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I had the following code snippet

```html
WITH sequences AS
  (SELECT 1 AS id, [STRUCT(0 AS a, 1 AS b)] AS some_numbers
   UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS id, [STRUCT(2 AS b, 4 AS a)] AS some_numbers
   UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS id, [STRUCT(5 AS b, 3 AS a), STRUCT (7 AS b, 4 AS a)]
     AS some_numbers)
SELECT id AS matching_rows
FROM sequences
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM UNNEST(some_numbers)
              WHERE b > 3);
```

And I got the following output

```html
Row matching_rows 
1     2
2       3
```

As per the where condition the result must be 3rd row only. Why it shows 2nd row also..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struct fields are unioned by position, not name. So this:

```sql
WITH sequences AS
  (SELECT 1 AS id, [STRUCT(0 AS a, 1 AS b)] AS some_numbers
   UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS id, [STRUCT(2 AS b, 4 AS a)] AS some_numbers
   UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS id, [STRUCT(5 AS b, 3 AS a), STRUCT (7 AS b, 4 AS a)]
     AS some_numbers)
SELECT id AS matching_rows
FROM sequences
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM UNNEST(some_numbers)
              WHERE b > 3);
```

is equivalent to this:

```sql
WITH sequences AS
  (SELECT 1 AS id, [STRUCT(0 AS a, 1 AS b)] AS some_numbers
   UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS id, [STRUCT(2 AS a, 4 AS b)] AS some_numbers
   UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS id, [STRUCT(5 AS a, 3 AS b), STRUCT (7 AS a, 4 AS b)]
     AS some_numbers)
SELECT id AS matching_rows
FROM sequences
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM UNNEST(some_numbers)
              WHERE b > 3);
```

Aside from the first query in the union, too, you can remove the `AS <name>` aliases since they don't affect the result.